# VS CODE, Can't link and compile multiple files of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, g++

I am learning C++ and using VS CODE as my editor. The problem is that my compiler says that it can't find the header files created by me.

```
Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g C:\Users\berkb\Desktop\codes\accpp\mains\test.cpp -o C:\Users\berkb\Desktop\codes\accpp\mains\test.exe
C:\Users\berkb\Desktop\codes\accpp\mains\test.cpp:7:10: fatal error: split.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include "split.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

I included them all in a separate folder inside my workspace folder, I also added their exact path to my c_cpp_properties.json file.
I am not really sure what the problem is so here are my c_cpp_properties.json, task.json files.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/berkb/Desktop/codes/accpp/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I would suggest instead of writing the hierarchy structure of your project to the c_cpp_properties.json file you should instead compile it on the terminal or even better learn a build automation tool like CMake .

Comment: One bug is here: `"${file}",` this means to build only the active file into the executable instead of building all your cpp files. The documentation tells you how to change it here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense not compiling. You need to additionally add the include directories to your `tasks.json`